# How do I add Cygwin bash shell to vs code?

Tags: c, bash, cygwin, visual-studio-code

I'm new to coding and just started with C. I have taken a coding class in udemy to learn C. But during the installation of bash.exe the guy in the video set it up but I couldn't by using his method. Please help.

Comment: Please post the link to the video. Also describe what yoy tried and what hapoened. Use as much detail as possible, i.e. exact commands and error messages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.